# How to crack password hashed using SSHA?

Tags: passwords, hash

Is it possible to crack a password hashed using SSHA if I know the salt? How can I do it?

Comment: Depending on the format, you might have to convert the hash/salt to/from hex/base64 for JtR or Hashcat to work on them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SSHA,  or more commonly known as salted SHA1  can be easily cracked with [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/).

Comment: as i know it is very hard to crack it because of salt. i used to crack md5, sha,... using online decryptors , but no online dycryptor for ssha

Comment: @USER1028 haha,  that is a funny one.  I don't think you understand why a salt is used.  SHA1 is a very fast hash function,  this will crack very quickly.

Comment: salt is something added to original password then it is hashed. salt used to make it hard to crack it ,right?

Comment: @user1028 A salt is added for 2 reasons.  1,  to prevent two passwords from yielding the same hash.  2,  to prevent pre-computed attacks like rainbowtables.  You can provide JTR the salt as an argument, so its is exactly the same speed as if it didn't have a salt.

Comment: If you've got a GPU with OpenCL or CUDA support, you should use [oclHashcat](http://hashcat.net/) - it'll be hundreds of times faster than your CPU.

Comment: @Polynomial JTR has gpu support.

Answer (score 3):

SSHA is a variant of SHA-1 with a salt included in the computation. This algorithm is used in some LDAP servers and originally comes from a Netscape internal draft specification. There are apparently several variants; see [this page](https://blogs.oracle.com/DirectoryManager/entry/the_ssha_password_storage_scheme) for a description of one used by an Oracle product, and [that page](http://coding.debuntu.org/php-how-calculate-ssha-value-string) for some PHP code which purports to compute the same function. They differ by the size of the salt (64 bits vs 32 bits). However, they have the same structure: a single [SHA-1](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips180-4/fips-180-4.pdf) computation over the concatenation of the password and the salt, and some encoding on the resulting value (some Base64, with the salt, and a recognizable header).

The function is salted; that's good. This is effective against precomputed tables, in particular the much touted [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table).

The function is not iterated; that's bad. For an attacker knowing the hash, "trying" a potential password is a matter of a single SHA-1 computation over a short input (less than the 64 bytes of an elementary internal SHA-1 block size), and that can be computed real fast. A single SHA-1 computation is about one thousand 32-bit operations. A basic x86 core will need 500 clock cycles for that (at most); with [SSE2 opcodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2), in the context of password cracking, this falls to about 200 clock cycles per SHA-1. Thus, a quad-core Core2 at 2.4 GHz will try 48 million passwords per second (that's what my code achieved, at least). A good [GPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPU) will be much better, since GPU are very good at 32-bit operations; *one billion* password hashes per second is a realistic figure.

There are not many passwords which resist cracking attempts which can try one billion passwords per second. Even [famous methods](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase) for generating passwords with 44 bits of entropy will last two or three hours on average.

Answer (score 1):

U could also use, **[Cain and Able](http://www.oxid.it/cain.html)** to crack password encrypted with that encryption algorithm.

Comment: Hashing is not encryption since it does not have inverse function nor a secret involved.