# OpenLDAP security SSHA

Tags: hash, sha, ldap

In OpenLDAP documentation I can find information that it supports the following encryption schemes: MD5, SMD5, SHA and SSHA.

From these schemes the most secure is SSHA (SHA-1 with salt), but it still usus SHA-1 which has been compromised and can be crracked using tools like John the Ripper or Cain and Abel - [How to crack password hashed using SSHA?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17592/how-to-crack-password-hashed-using-ssha).

Is it possible to configure LDAP in other way? Should I use LDAP?
Is it secure if I will use salt which will be at least eight octets (64 bits) long according to http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt.

Comment: https://auth0.com/blog/sha-1-collision-attack/

Comment: https://www.redpill-linpro.com/techblog/2016/08/16/ldap-password-hash.html

Comment: Those are not encryption schemes they're password hashes, and they're all terrible. I found [this](https://github.com/hamano/openldap-pbkdf2) and [this](https://github.com/wclarie/openldap-bcrypt) with a quick search. PBKDF2 appears to have been added to the project's [source](https://github.com/winlibs/openldap/tree/master/contrib/slapd-modules/passwd/pbkdf2) as a module.